# How to produce axes that do not intersect at (0, 0)?

Tags: d3.js

I would like to generate axes that do not intersect at (0, 0) (and also do not necessarily coincide with the edges of a plot), as shown in the example below.

How can I do this with `d3`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will first need to figure out where you want to display the axis. If they are fixed to canvas, take ratios of width and height.

Here's an example that I made:

http://vida.io/documents/zB4P4fjHz79um3qzX

x-axis is at to 2/3 of height:

```
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height * 2 / 3 + ")")
```

And y-axis is at 1/3 of width:

```
.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 3 + ", 0)")
```

If you need the axis relative to range of values, calculate them based on range. For example:

```
var domain = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.y_axis; })
var y_axis_pos = width * (y_axis_value - domain[1]) / (domain[0] - domain[1]);
// svg code...
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + y_axis_pos + ", 0)")
```

Answer (score 1):

From the D3.js [API documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-orient):

> to change the position of the axis with respect to the plot, specify a transform attribute on the containing g element.